# Facing problem adding footer in the last page vf rendered as pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I want to add some text on end of the last page as footer in the vf page rendered as pdf. I have tried with @page :last { }. But It is not working. Any idea?

css:

```
@page {

    @top-center {

    content: element(header);

    }

    @bottom-left {

        content: element(footer);

    }
}


@page :last {
  color: green;

  @bottom-center {
    content: "text...";
    color: blue;
  }
}



div.header {

padding: 10px;

position: running(header);

}

div.footer {

display: block;

padding: 5px;

position: running(footer);

}



.pagenumber:before {

content: counter(page);

}

.pagecount:before {

content: counter(pages);

}
```

Page:

```
<div class = "header">
------
</div>
 <div class="content">
---some content--------------------
</div>
<div class = "footer">
----some content ---
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally to do what you're attempting, your footer would be defined using an `@page` as well as an `@media`. You'd do the same with the psuedo-class of `page:last`. I don't see any markup in your page layout to provide for the last:page to appear. It would seem you'd want to include it in the div where your footer appears and have it as a child of the footer.

Here's an example of what you'd normally expect to see:

```
@page {
    margin : 70pt .5in .5in .5in;

    @top-center {
        content : "My Header";
     }
    @bottom-left {
        content : "My Footer on Left Side";
        font-size : 10 px;
        color : #808080;
    }
    @bottom-center {
        content : "My last page content in center" ;
        font-size : 10 px;
        color : #808080;
    }
}
```

You may need to do something like this where it's defined as a child of your element `footer`:

```
footer.page:last {

    // add spacing element so it appears in center

    content: text;

}
```

To assist with that, you *may* also need to relate it to a `.pagenumber:last`.

As a final note, it's important to remember that PDFs only support CSS 2.1, not CSS 3. So any CSS 3 notation may or may not work. Check the [FlyingSaucer Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) for the latest revisions.

Answer (score 0):

You may @bottom of page in CSS part and then in the body use 
`<div class="footer">`

```
@bottom-left {
    content: element(footer);
}

div.footer {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
    font: 10pt;
    position: running(footer);
}
```